# PHP isset not working with blanks

Tags: php, isset

I am just getting back in to PHP after many years and building a basic sit to start things off.

I have an index.php on my root and want to check for input from isset when either the value is ?home or just simply blank.

So easy enough I can start with:

```
if (isset($_GET['home']))
{
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/content.html.php';
}
```

But my issue is trying to get it to work if there is nothing to get?  I can see a couple of ways to do it but I think I am missing something simple to add to the first line.

Any help appreciated.

Lee

Comment: if (isset($_GET['home']) && $_GET['home'] != '' )) { 
does this work ?

Comment: Use [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), if  home is not numeric

Comment: @pNre: `var_dump(empty(0));`

Comment: if (isset($_GET['home']) && $_GET['home'] > '' ))

Comment: if your issue is that `home` is present but has no value, e.g. `www.example.com?home=&another` if so, you can use `key_exists('home', $_GET)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset()` checks if a variable has a value including `( False , 0 , or empty string)` , but not `NULL`. Returns `TRUE` if variable exists otherwise returns `FALSE`.

On the other hand the `empty()` function checks if the variable has an `empty value, empty string , 0, NULL ,or False`. Returns `FALSE` if variable has a `non-empty` and `non-zero` value.

For details have a look here

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Thanks shuvo that prompted me to read isset again, so if nothing is selected I was thinking isset would accept that as an empty string but not the case.  Empty is where I needed to look.


    if (isset($_GET['home']) || (empty($_GET)) )

Comment: empty will also check to see if the variable is set, so you don't need isset at all.